# In org-agenda, highlight marked entries

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, highlighting, hl-line-mode

Running Doom Emacs v2.0.9 on Emacs 27.1.

I can mark several entries in the agenda buffer and work on all of them together.

Is there a way to keep marked entries highlighted? This would give more comfort while we operate on them.

Answer (score 0):

Your question should be more accurate. You can compose a function to do what you want. For instance to highlight saturday and monday using the color pink (you can have a try in interactive mode ):

```
(defun my-highlight-we-agenda ()
" your function description "
(highlight-regexp "saturday\\|sunday" 'hi-pink))
```

Next you active this function in any org-agenda-list buffer

```
(add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook #'my-highlight-we-agenda)
```

To compose a regexp just as you need, you can use re-builder in a org-agenda buffer

Comment: Thanks. But that was not what I meant. In agenda buffer, one can mark an entry using `org-agenda-bulk-toggle`. This puts a small icon in the leftmost column. Can we have the line highlighted instead?

Comment: Could you post an example of your org-agenda buffer and what you want to be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will highlight all marked lines in yellow, and unhighlight unmarked lines. I add advice to run it after all commands that mark and unmark entries:

```lisp
;; Highlight lines of marked Org-Agenda items
;; See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/70380/17182
(defun my-org-agenda-highlight-marked (oldfun &rest r)
  ;; ‘advice--cd*r’ finds the underlying advised function so that we can
  ;; properly compare functions.
  (let* ((oldfun-base (advice--cd*r oldfun))
         ;; Functions that examine the whole buffer and are not implemented
         ;; in terms of more primitive functions - currently just
         ;; ‘org-agenda-bulk-unmark-all'.
         (all-buffer-funcs
                   (mapcar (lambda (sym)
                             (advice--cd*r (symbol-function sym)))
                           '(org-agenda-bulk-unmark-all)))
         (begin
          (cond
           ((member oldfun all-buffer-funcs) (point-min))
           ((use-region-p) (region-beginning))
           (t (point-at-bol))))
         (end
          (cond
           ((member oldfun all-buffer-funcs) (point-max))
           ((use-region-p) (region-end))
           (t (point-at-eol)))))
    (apply oldfun r)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char begin)
      (forward-line 0)
      (while (< (point) end)
        (let* ((ovs (overlays-at (point)))
               (marked-entry-overlay
                (nth 0
                     (cl-remove-if-not
                      (lambda (ov)
                        (eq (overlay-get ov 'type) 'org-marked-entry-overlay))
                      ovs)))
               (highlight-marked-overlay
                (nth 0
                     (cl-remove-if-not
                      (lambda (ov)
                        (eq (overlay-get ov 'type) 'my-org-agenda-highlight-marked))
                      ovs))))
          (cond
           ((and highlight-marked-overlay (not marked-entry-overlay))
            (delete-overlay highlight-marked-overlay))
           ((and marked-entry-overlay (not highlight-marked-overlay))
            (let ((ov (make-overlay (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol))))
              (overlay-put ov 'type 'my-org-agenda-highlight-marked)
              (overlay-put ov 'face '(:background "yellow"))))))
        (forward-line 1)))))
;; ‘org-agenda-bulk-mark-all’, ‘org-agenda-bulk-mark-regexp’, and
;; ‘org-agenda-bulk-toggle-all’ are all implemented using
;; ‘org-agenda-bulk-mark’, and ‘org-agend-bulk-toggle’, so
;; they don't need to be advised.
(dolist (cmd '(org-agenda-bulk-mark org-agenda-bulk-toggle
               org-agenda-bulk-unmark org-agenda-bulk-unmark-all))
  (advice-add cmd :around #'my-org-agenda-highlight-marked))
```